# Does SSI support restlet SE version

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

I am looking to avoid using iframes and was wondering, if
anyone knows if server side includes are supported in restlet se?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so but there are extension libraries for both FreeMarker http://restlet.org/learn/guide/2.1/extensions/freemarker and Velocity http://restlet.org/learn/guide/2.1/extensions/velocity with which you will potentially be able to achieve the result you desire, although I cannot be sure with so little detail.